# Cypher - remove subgraph from results

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have the following graph
[graph layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAtSc.png)

As you can see, the graph the following relationships:

1. `(u::4)-[ADDED_RESOURCE]->(:resource)<-[ADDED_RESOURCE]-(u::3) \\ u::4, u::3 are the ids of the nodes`.
2. `(u::4)-[UNLINK]->(u::3)`

I'm using APOC to traverse the graph like so:

```
MATCH (u:user {id:"u::1"}
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(u,{minLevel:1,maxLevel:6,bfs:true,uniqueness:"NODE_PATH",labelFilter:">resource"}) YIELD path
with u, path, filter(n in nodes(path) where n:resource) as resources
unwind resources as resource
MATCH (rus:user)-[]->(resource)
RETURN distinct rus.id
```

This returns all the `u::X` nodes that are related to node `u::1` via it's related resources.

Because `u::4` and `u::3` are unlinked, I would like the traversal to ignore that connection and not return the subgraph that's related to `u::3`. So instead of returning `u::4, u::3, u::2, u::5`, it should return only `u::4`.

Is there a way to tell APOC to ignore nodes that have a certain relationship between them while traversing?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think apoc.path.expandConfig will allow you to ignore a list of relationship types but it will follow positively expressed relationship types.  And it can optionally account for order with `<`,`>`.

```
MATCH (u:user {id:"u::1"}
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(u
  {
    minLevel:1,
    maxLevel:6,
    bfs:true,
    uniqueness:"NODE_PATH",
    labelFilter:">resource",

    // add relationship filter to folow only relationships that are included
    relationshipFilter: 'ADDED_RESOURCE|OTHER_TYPE|...'
}) YIELD path
with u, path, filter(n in nodes(path) where n:resource) as resources
UNWIND resources as resource
MATCH (rus:user)-[]->(resource)
RETURN distinct rus.id
```

Comment: thanks, but if I wish to maintain both the `UNLINK` and the `ADDED_RESOURCE` links, I'll be in a problem. It will still return all the users that are connected regardless of the `UNLINK` relationship.